# Unsuccessful Ajax to PHP post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My Ajax script keeps returning a result of unsuccessful.  The console doesn't appear to show any errors.  It just keeps throwing the alert window saying "error" instead of showing the result.

Ajax

```
$.ajax
({
  url: 'query.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType:'json',
  data: {Category: 'test'},
  success: function(result) 
  {    
    if(result) 
    {          
      console.log(result);
      alert(result);
    }
  },
  error: function() 
  {
    alert("error");
  }      
}); // end ajax call
```

php

```
$cat = $_POST['Category'];
echo $cat;
```

Comment: What is the actual response your AJAX call receives? You can find out in the network inspector section of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: DOes your php have opening `<?php` tag?

Comment: Well, you told jQuery.ajax that the request will be returning JSON and it isn't, so the error callback is triggered.

Comment: the error callback has 3 parameters (request, status, error), those would help to print more than alerting "error"

Comment: @rickdenhaan - Under the XHR tab it says query.php - I assume thats what you're referring to?

Comment: @Ismail correct. If that request is returning a 200 OK response, consider what Musa said.

Comment: remove this `dataType:'json',` and try again.

Comment: Thanks guys - it was as you said. Removing the JSON datatype fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

please check your `query.php`  page. and make sure this page return some response either data or error massage like `statusText="Error"`.

Answer (score 0):

Do **ajax function** like below

```
$.ajax({ url: 'query.php',
type: 'POST',
dataType:'json',
data: {Category: 'test'},
success: function(result) 
{
if(result.success=="TRUE")
{
console.log(result);
alert(result.cat);
}
},
error: function()
{
alert("error");
}
});
```

In **query.php**

```
$cat=$_POST['category'];
if(!empty($cat)){
$data['success']="TRUE";
$data['message'] = "Category Found.";
$data['cat']='$cat';
}
else{
$data['success'] = "False";
$data['message'] = "Category not found.";
}
die(json_encode($data));
```

Answer (score -1):

[jquery ajax document](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

#### option 1

response a `json` from `php`

example: `echo "{}";`

#### option 2

remove `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: Thanks guys - it was as you said. Removing the JSON datatype fixed it